# Deploying JavaBridge on Glassfish server

Tags: java, php, glassfish, quercus

I'm trying to install JavaBridge on Glassfish server. 
It is installed as I can see its start page on http://localhost/JavaBridge/.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gycwX.jpg)

However, when I'm trying to access it from php code (using quercus-4.0.39 that it also successfully deployed) it doesn't work.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 
    require_once("http://localhost/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
    $myJavaClass = java("myJavaClass");
?>
```

$myJavaClass is null, but *http://localhost/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc* is correct address for the file *Java.inc*, and *myJavaClass.jar* in folder *\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\lib* (the same myJavaClass.jar class worked successfully with tomcat+xampp).

Can somebody, please, explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is better to upload an image directly into the question, since link addresses  may change over time.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points for uploading an image directly to my question.